# What do I use to cap a kitchen sink sprayer hose?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

My kitchen sink has a sprayer. I want to remove it. I believe I would need a cap to seal off the connection after I take the sprayer hose off. I saw a few articles saying you need to get a "3/8-inch threaded brass flair cap". Is that correct? Picture below, was the best I could snap under there:

[image]

I want to go to a home supply store to get whatever cap I would need, but not sure what to ask them for.

The corrosion under there looks pretty gross.

Thanks

Comment: If you could remove the hose from the faucet and post a picture of the end of the faucet fitting and inside end of the hose, with something there to give scale (tape measure?) we could be of better help.

Comment: If you take it apart, you could take the sprayer with you to match the correct cap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 3/8" is the correct size, I believe you need a 3/8" FIP cap (FIP stands for Female Iron Pipe) also known as a 3/8" female NPT cap. If the size is actually 1/2", then obviously you'd need in the 1/2" size.

You would also need pipe dope or teflon pipe dealing tape The dope comes in a smaller size in a tube or larger size in a jar. IP does not mean you'd get it in iron or steel. You'd probably get it in brass.

Comment: Where is the leak in the sprayer? at the threads or the hose? Maybe you could just tighten the sprayer hose.